# Could post annotations be put next to their posts instead of after the comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, post-notices

A post that has earned the "sources needed" annotation usually (in my experience) has several comments explaining what the problems in the post are.  These comments are still relevant (until the author addresses them), so they shouldn't be flushed or hidden.  But they push the annotation down on the page where it can be more easily missed.  Annotations are [supposed to be rare](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172607/162102); when they are used at all, therefore, they should be clear to all readers so the problems can be addressed one way or the other.  Right now, though, they can get kind of lost on the page.

Shouldn't an annotation, being an intentional moderator action, have some priority placement?  Can we improve on this?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: I propose a large lock icon that could be placed below the voting arrows. [/randomly throwing out an idea without reading]

Comment: I agree: Post annotations should be more important than comments. They should be read before any comment.

Comment: What is "sources needed annotation"/"post annotation"? Do you have a source? *[What are these notices under my post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post)*? Is *post notice* the same as *post annotation*? I am confused.

Comment: Sorry @PeterMortensen; I thought the screen shot would be sufficient documentation.

Comment: Perhaps it should be in the *[Stack Exchange Glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)* (?)

Comment: It seems they are also [called *banners*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102363/support-for-banners), but *post notice* may be the official term as there is *[a tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/post-notice/info)*.

Comment: The tag here is "post-notice", the mod tools have a link for "annotated posts" but the action to create one is "add post notice", and they're sometimes called "banners".  So I think the confusion is broader than my question. :-)