# Do custom reasons/notes for bounties get preserved after awarding?

Tags: discussion, bounties, bounty-remarks

When posting a bounty, users get opportunity to add an optional explanation for why the bounty is posted, on top of standard multiple choice.

That note is posted under the bounty panel while the bounty is open.

Is that note preserved after the bounty is awarded?

(the reason for asking is, I try to come up with moderatly non-dull reason wordings... and if they get lost post-award I don't want to invest too much effort in doing so).

Comment: I suspect this is a dupe of several Qs asking to allow keeping the message (which kind of assumes it isn't kept now). But none of them have answers so I'm not sure

Comment: While I've personally witnessed questions here get up to maybe 5 or even 10 score without any actual necessity (i.e., status-norepro), getting to 91 without any foundation is far less likely. I think you can figure it really isn't implemented yet. (And I know I've never been able to dig them up.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mention, [several questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110003/300411) request that the custom message be preserved.  As of now, it is not preserved in the most natural location for it, the post's revision history.  For example, [this post](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/posts/31344/revisions) definitely had a custom message (I wrote one) but the revision history shows only the category I selected:

> [image]

No tooltips provide my text either.

The other place this information might be would be on SEDE, but [according to the schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/300411), it isn't provided there either: just start, close, and amount.  See [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252633/300411).

Comment: My idea was to preserve it in the hover-over message on the bounty badge. Far more visible than post history

Comment: @soup = make badge a link; on clicking display full bounty list/details - as popup, hover-over or a panel