# Weird post-notice comments appearing for bounties in flag history

Tags: bug, bounties, moderator-tools, timeline

For a question which has been both bountied and flagged at some time in the past, the **post's flag history page** shows some strange and unexpected things in the "Comment" column for the **starting/ending bounty** events in the post's history.

I'll include links, but they're visible only to diamond bearers on the respective sites, so I'll also include screenshots with any non-public information redacted.

---

- **Exhibit 1:** https://literature.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/2536/show-flags

  As you can see from the [public timeline](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/2536/revisions), bounties have been offered on this post twice. But the flag history page shows:

  [image]

---

- **Exhibit 2:** https://scifi.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/111992/show-flags

  As you can see from the [public timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/111992/timeline), this post was bountied in 2016. But the flag history page shows:

  [image]

---

(Click for full sized versions of these screenshot images.)

In the first case, the bounty comment looks like a close reason. In the second case, I've no idea *what* that is. What's going on here?

Comment: [Another case on SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/121097/show-flags) with some weird numbers appearing there (this time 1172 and 1261 for two different bounties).

Comment: [Another case on Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/1780/show-flags) with "Not suitable for this site" appearing there again.

Comment: Technically that is the value in the comment of [the posthistory table](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1252714) but I agree a lookup of that [foreign key to postnotices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252633/in-the-posthistory-table-what-is-that-number-in-the-comment-column) would be nice.

Comment: Getting strange numbers as well on RPG.se for the couple posts I checked "2544" and "2545"