# Let gold tag badge holders add post notices?

Tags: feature-request, post-notices

This isn't

> [Allow high-reputation users to add post notices (perhaps as a 30k privilege?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141931/allow-high-reputation-users-10k-15k-or-20k-to-add-post-notices)

I'm suggesting we let gold tag badge holders add post notices (even if it's just a subset).

This way experts,  who can't know everything on a subject, will be able to point out when a post needs references.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to what [I wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278856/1438) on the related question:

### Tags with gold badge holders are somewhat rare.

Gold badges are a pretty clever way to deal with duplicates: as the number of questions in a tag grow, gold badges scale right alongside. I really like the idea of tying post notices to expertise in a tag, but nobody on Skeptics has a [gold](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=gold) or [silver](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=silver) tag badge. There are a few [bronze tag badges](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=bronze), but I don't suppose that collection is very useful. I could see this privilege being given to people how have either a rather high reputation *or* some level of badge in the question's tags. But I think it would be best to start with a [reputation-based privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141931/1438).

Comment: Thanks for your input Jon. We've got a [few](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=gold) gold tag badge holders on sci-fi, and I feel it might benefit us to implement that there.