# Badge for helping with UI-text translation/localization on non-English international sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badge-request, localization, translations

Good behaviour encouraged: help add localizations for UI text on international non-English sites.

- Bronze: 1 translation contributed
- Silver: I don't know (discuss!)
- Gold: I don't know

I don't know how this would be implemented. I don't know much about [traducir.win](https://github.com/g3rv4/Traducir), but my understanding is that it's a community-built shell UI around a SE-integrated [i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) mechanism.

For people who think we should *not* have such badges, please post an answer and share why! Let your voice and your reasoning be heard!

Comment: This feature-request was made in response to [this community role suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384188/997587).

Comment: This exists completely separately from whatever is going on in that thread. I purposely write this feature-request as a "counter-proposal" to the "translator" role proposal there because I that role proposal doesn't indicate a need for more tools/privileges for a person in that role to do their job, which seems to be the actual point of that discussion: find roles that need more privileges/tools to be more efficient. If the translator role designation is only proposed in order to gain attention to the existance of the role and attract contributos, we already have the badge mechanism.

Comment: @Joachim new role is super complex, and will take long years to be actually done, if ever. New badge is quite simple, requires less development efforts, and has better chance to be done.