# How often do visitors land on "Page not found" pages due to deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, statistics

From time to time, questions are deleted. This results in "Page not found" pages. Are there any public stats on how often people land on "Page not found" pages?

Answer (score 11):

Nothing public that I'm aware of, no. I can certainly share some ad hoc data I just pulled from January from Stack Overflow because you piqued my curiosity.

#### TL;DR: Not often.

I don't have an easy or reliable way to determine how many 404s are *legitimate* 404s for questions that have actually been deleted (or at least were deleted at the time), and weren't simple typos, malformed links, or incomplete copy & paste. Nothing in those logs or the response headers say *"this was 404 **because** the post was deleted"* - all we know (without parsing the URL and trying to match back to a question on the given host's database, also prohibitively expensive to satisfy curiosity) is that the server returned a 404 response.

Because of this I also can't easily determine how many users *with the ability to see deleted questions* actually visited deleted questions *that were deleted at the time*, because they get a 200 response just like if the question *were not* deleted. And since a question can move in and out of states, even making that (very expensive) correlation would not be extremely reliable.

Anyway, as with many other questions: even if the log data *could* differentiate between 404s because the question was deleted and 404s because of a typo, now what?

---

Adding some info about referers, this is a tough thing to combine with *aggregation* because even at the host level the tail is extremely long (and the majority of traffic doesn't log a referer in general). For January, here are the top 15 *hosts* (+ no referer) that led to the 404s we can determine (e.g. these still don't include 10K users who followed a link to a deleted question), updated to remove crawlers we can programmatically identify:

> [image: 404s by referring host and anonymous or not]

Of course a lot of this is just expected and can't really be eliminated. 10K users will often post links to questions that later get deleted (or even that are already deleted) and those links will live on forever. A link can be posted to twitter or reddit or {name your poison} and the Streisand effect leads to the question getting down-voted / closed / deleted. I think it would be extremely challenging to sift through potentially millions of 404 events and pluck out the ones we can do anything about.

Comment: Considering Stack Overflow [has around 6.8m visits a day](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), these 404s are like 7% to 12% of all visits, which sounds significant

Comment: the last one may include deleted questions, though (or may not?)

Comment: Anyway, 404s seem to largely be in the 1% range, and I don't know how to estimate what % of that is due to user error, but I am confident it is not 0. Is a lot of 404s bad? Sure. But I don't know what we can do short of finding some way to analyze every single one, find out where they're coming from, and try to fix the source (which isn't always going to be in our control, and sometimes there is no source because the user typed it or pasted it wrong).

Comment: Could you include referers? I'm guessing many of the unauthenticated ones come from search engines, where Google tends to have results from recent questions which could have been deleted between the time they were indexed and someone searched. Similarly, for authenticated users, I'm guessing some will have referers which reveal broken links or 10k+ only links.

Comment: @tripleee Added some info about referers, but I don't know if it will be very useful.

Comment: Damn man you're so dedicated! Expect a fat bounty once I can award it, the least I can do to show some appreciation. :-)

Comment: This figure could possibly be reduced slightly as a part of [Help us identify new roles for community members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384169/276027) particularly https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384293/276027